# How do I get the check out/in banner to stop appearing?

Tags: word, check-out, check-in

[image: Check in banner]
I have opened a document from share point into word and the above banner is at the top of my document. It is very distracting by being a different color to the rest of the screen and its blue icon. I have tried pressing the X at the right hand side of it and it keeps coming back, within seconds.

is there a way of disabling this banner or removing it from view somehow without disabling the check in/out functionality?

edit: clarity of question.

Comment: I've found turning off Autosave stops it. Not a fix, but but a workaround

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want check-in and check-out functionality then you can disable check-in and check-out on a SharePoint document library:

1. Navigate to the SharePoint document library on which you want to disable check-in and check-out.
2. On the Settings menu, click Document Library Settings.
3. On the Customise page under General Settings, click Versioning settings.
4. On the Document Library Versioning Settings page, `select NO for Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?`, and click OK.

Comment: Mind you, that will disable the functionality itself. If OP wanted just to dismiss the annoying yellow alert but keep the functionality, I am not entirely sure that is possible out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to the SharePoint site that hosts the document using a browser.  I checked it out there and then checked it back in.  I then opened the document on my desktop version of word.  That stopped the pesky banner from appearing again.

That banner normally behaves correctly for me until I check in the file for the first time. But the problem that is being presented for some folks is that this banner keeps coming back.  It should only display until the document is checked in for the first time.  Then it shouldn't reappear.  In this case this banner keeps coming back even though the file has been checked in from the desktop version of Word.  I think on occasion the flag that indicates this file has been checked in as some point has not been set.  By forcing it in the web interface it appears to clear that flag.

I hope this helps some folks.

Comment: This is basically what fixed it for me. The only difference was I checked the document in using Excel (File -> Info -> Check In). Then I closed Excel, reopened it, and checked the document out again. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer - however it could help other people with the same issue. In order to get rid of the banner all you need to do is save your document and it will disappear forever.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on Edit, then click on "Check In" button to remove that sign

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is infuriating. Microsoft is not addressing the issue either. They are just suggesting to disable the check in/check out functionality on their support forum.
In PowerPoint it keeps popping up when I am making a change to the document, and thus resizing the screen. It drives me mad.
An easy fix would be to just remove the popup and have an indication at the bottom of the screen or something.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I found this question because it was also driving me nuts.   The best workaround I've come up with is the following:

1. Go to File -> Info
2. Click the "Check In" button
3. Note changes to this draft (optional) and click the box for "Keep the document checked out after checking in this version."
4. Powerpoint will save the file, and then the annoying Check-In banner will appear again, only this time it will stay there and not flash off immediately.  As long as you don't close the banner yourself, it will stay open.

While it doesn't eliminate the banner, it does eliminate the seizure-inducing flashing and resizing of the screen every time it auto-saves.   HTH!